# How do I prevent the loading of duplicate rows in to an Oracle table?

Tags: oracle, duplicates

I have some large tables (millions of rows).  I constantly receive files containing new rows to add in to those tables - up to 50 million rows per day.  Around 0.1% of the rows I receive are duplicates of rows I have already loaded (or are duplicates within the files).  I would like to prevent those rows being loaded in to the table.

I currently use SQL*Loader in order to have sufficient performance to cope with my large data volume.  If I take the obvious step and add a unique index on the columns which goven whether or not a row is a duplicate, SQL*Loader will start to fail the entire file which contains the duplicate row - whereas I only want to prevent the duplicate row itself being loaded.

I know that in SQL Server and Sybase I can create a unique index with the 'Ignore Duplicates' property and that if I then use BCP the duplicate rows (as defined by that index) will simply not be loaded.

Is there some way to achieve the same effect in Oracle?

I do not want to remove the duplicate rows once they have been loaded - it's important to me that they should never be loaded in the first place.

Comment: How are you loading the files - SQL*Loader/Data Pump?

Comment: Currently using SQL*Loader.  Because of the large volume of data, performance is important to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you mean by "duplicate"? If you have a column which defines a unique row you should setup a unique constraint against that column. One typically creates a unique index on this column, which will automatically setup the constraint.

EDIT:
Yes, as commented below you should setup a "bad" file for SQL*Loader to capture invalid rows. But I think that establishing the unique index is probably a good idea from a data-integrity standpoint.

Comment: A very good point - I should have mentioned though that I am loading up to 50 million rows per day and therefore want to use SQL*Loader to carry out the data load.  I believe that SQL*Loader will fail the entire file if it contains duplicates which violate a unique index.

Comment: You can tell SQL*Loader what to do with rejected rows.  Try specifying a 'badfile' parameter on the command line, with a suitably high 'errors' parameter.

Comment: @Adam - sorry, that was directed at ginsoakedboy, not you.  I reckon a combination of a unique index and suitable SQL*Loader parameters is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Use Oracle MERGE statement. Some explanations [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/MergeEnhancements10g.php).

Answer (score 2):

You dint inform about what release of Oracle you have. Have a look at there for [merge command](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/oracle9i/daily/Aug24.html).

Basically like this

```
---- Loop through all the rows from a record temp_emp_rec
MERGE INTO hr.employees e
     USING temp_emp_rec t
     ON (e.emp_ID = t.emp_ID)
     WHEN MATCHED THEN
    --- _You can update_
    UPDATE
     SET first_name = t.first_name,
          last_name = t.last_name
    --- _Insert into the table_
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (emp_id, first_name, last_name)
    VALUES (t.emp_id, t.first_name, t.last_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use integrity constraints defined on the appropriate table columns.

This [page](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/data_int.htm#sthref2976) from the Oracle concepts manual gives an overview, if you also scroll down you will see what types of constraints are available.

Comment: A good approach to be sure, but in order to meet my performance needs (50 million rows/day) I am using SQL*Loader to load the rows.  I think that SQL*Loader will fail entire files if they contain duplicates if I add such an index, which isn't acceptable for my application.

Answer (score 1):

use below option, if you will get this much error 9999999 after that your sqlldr will terminate.

```
OPTIONS (ERRORS=9999999, DIRECT=FALSE )
LOAD DATA
```

you will get duplicate records in bad file.

```
sqlldr user/password@schema CONTROL=file.ctl, LOG=file.log, BAD=file.bad
```